# Why isn't my code changing the background color of a cell in excel using openpyxl in Python?

Tags: python, openpyxl

I need to change the colour of some cells in excel with python.

I've tried with openpyxl but it doesn´t work correctly.

First, I took the file and opened the correct sheet

```
import os, openpyxl
from openpyxl.styles import PatternFill

file = os.getcwd() + '\\File.xlsx'
wb = load_workbook(file)
sheet = wb.active
```

Then, I tried to select the cell and change the colour

```
# Specify the range of cells

cell = sheet['A1']


# Create the fill color

cell.fill = PatternFill(start_color='FF0000', end_color='FF0000', fill_type='solid')  # Red color

wb.save(file)
```

When I ran this code I didn't get any error, but it didn't make any changes

Comment: Did your code save the file afterwards?  Please show the full script, not just the two lines in question.

Comment: Yes, I saved the file after that. I updated the code, now you can see the full script in the question. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

This will do the work

```
from openpyxl.styles import PatternFill, Color


cell.fill = PatternFill(patternType='solid', fill_type='solid', fgColor=Color('FF0000'))
```

Comment: It doesn't work. I think there are some problems with the version of python or something like that.